# How do I call this void function from another function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, void-pointers, dynamic-allocation

Basically I want duplicate to resize my array. The function next is suppose to search for next available location in the array. Once next hits 10 which is the max capacity I want it to call duplicate. Basically call duplicate if the array has been found to be full within the next function.

The problem is that when I get the loop to 10 numbers it fails on the 11th. After the 10th element is in, it goes into the duplicate function, then it goes to the pointer, then through the array, and then it just keeps looping, so when I use my function to see the total number of elements it still says 10, which means `maxsize` is not changing. I do not understand why?

```
void ProgramOne<Type>::Next(Type & y)
{
    if (!IsFull())
    {
        if (count < maxsize)
        {
            bag[count] = y;
            count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Duplicate();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call this

```
void ProgramOne<Type>::Duplicate()
{
        int *bagB = new int[maxsize * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
        {
            bagB[i] = bag[i];
        }
        delete[] bag;
        bag = bagB;
}
```

Comment: There seem to be some missing braces in `Duplicate`.

Comment: What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried making an int let's say f,g before it but then I thought that would require an input and would have to be in main. Then I tried (bag,size) but bag is a pointer so that wouldn't work too.

Comment: @jxh Sorry forgot to tag you. I tried many things but regardless it gives me the undeclared identifier error.

Comment: After jxh's comment, you edited in braces around three statements after the `for` loop, but you should only execute the first assignment statement inside the loop.  `delete[] bag;` and `bag = bagB;` can only be done after the copying.  More generally, the code's a mess: you shouldn't have a "Duplicate" member function that doesn't even use any member variables and doesn't return the new `maxsize`... as is, you have to duplicate the `* 2` knowledge outside `Duplicate` and hope they stay in sync during program maintenance/evolution.  Is there a reason you're not using a `std::vector`?

Comment: You can't ever have an instance of `void`.  (Your title makes no sense as written, you should have said "another function")

Comment: Can you show what you tried in code, and describe what it did instead of work as you expect?

Comment: @TonyD The reason is my professor is annoying and retarded. She wants it this way.

Comment: The call in your code is Duplication(), while the function name you have written is Duplicate()... can that be the reason?

Comment: @Ajit nope that was a typo on my end still fails

Comment: @jxh The problem is jxh that when I get the loop to 10 numbers it fails on the 11th. After the element 10 is in it goes into the duplicate function then it goes to the pointer then through the array and then it just keeps looping so when I use my function to see total number of elements it still says 10 which shows maxsize is not changing I do not know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Duplicate()` function fails to update `maxsize` after it is done copying the original elements. Before it returns, it should update the `maxsize` to what it had allocated for the new `bag`.

```
        delete[] bag;
        bag = bagB;
        maxsize *= 2;
```

Comment: You are very welcome. @TonyD spotted it first I see from the comments, though.